# Support PDF ID according to specification?

Tags: pdf

The PDF specification states about the PDF ID (section 14.4 of v1.7 of 2008):

[image: file identifier description in PDF specification]
(Sorry for the image, the document I have access to does not allow copying.)

I'm trying to implement or at least approximate this specification in LaTeX-generated documents.

A problem for that is obviously to recalculate the ID of the original version (first byte string), where the original source file often no longer exists when a later version is processed. However, I see two possible strategies:

1. If one assumes that the PDF is recreated in the same place (always overwriting previous versions), then a strategy to approximate this would be to extract the first byte string from the existing PDF and then to insert it into the newly created PDF, along with a new second byte string calculated from the current file's properties.
2. If one assumes that the pathname does not change, and if one ignores file size and information dictionary in the calculation of the ID, the first byte string could be calculated based on the pathname and the *creation time* of the source file (and the second based on the pathname and the modification time).

Both strategies could be combined: Check if the target PDF file exists and if yes, extract the first byte string, if not calculate it from pathname and source file creation time.

Now I'm aware that the different TeX engines / pdf creators provide commands to set the PDF ID explicitly. However, my TeX knowledge is not deep enough to figure out how one would extract the first byte string from an existing PDF file, or how to access the creation time of the source file – from within (La)TeX. I'm not even sure whether the first is possible, since at processing time that file might already have begun to be overwritten.

Therefore my question is a) is it possible to implement one of the strategies or the combination within (La)TeX, and if yes b) can you give me hints how to achieve that?

Comment: what's wrong with the automatically created ID?

Comment: That it doesn't conform to the specification. Apart from sticking to specifications being a good thing in itself, it leads to problems with some PDF viewers, which remember view settings in a dictionary with the ID as key.

Comment: the specification doesn't give details how the id should be calculated and the implementation notes explicity say "Note that the calculation of the file identifier need not be reproducible; all that matters is that the identifier is likely to be unique.". And in pdf 2.0 the text is actually different. Also I never had or heard of any problems with PDF's created by the various tex engines in this respect.

Comment: It says "the first byte string shall be a permanent identifier" – has that changed in PDF 2.0?

Comment: No, but this is not really relevant for tex, as we don't incrementally  change a pdf, we always create a new one.